# how to display the UISrcollView vertical Bar?

Tags: uiscrollview, uilabel

I define a UILabel inside a UIScrollView in my ipad.
But how to display the UISrcollView vertical Bar when the text is bigger than the scrollView ?
When I touch the scrollView the vertical bar appeared, but how to display it without touching ?
Regards
Fred

Answer (score 0):

I think, its not possible. Setting showsVerticalScrollIndicator and showsHorizontalScrollIndicator properties you can display the scroll bar.

You can use flashScrollIndicators when the view becomes visible. It will guide user that scrollable content is available.